# Tomcat HTTP Status 404 after switch location in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I created a spring web application in eclipse, with Tomcat as runtime server.

It worked fine,and I could see my app working using:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyAppName/
```

But once I did switch location(from workspace metadata to tomcat location ) in the tomcat server properties of eclipse, application is giving HTTP Status 404 when I am trying to access it by :

```
http://localhost:8080/MyAppName/
```

I followed this tutorial to create a sample helloworld web application in eclipse:
http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-mvc-hello-world/

Can someone help me know why this is happening?

I am using tomcat 7 + eclipse luna

Comment: show how you switched the location

Comment: Right click on server --> properties --> General --> switch location

Comment: Didn't understand your problem mate. How did you switch the workspace? Can you see the .metadata/..../wptwebapps/tmp0 or tmp1 folder in your workspace and see if the project is deployed in there?

Comment: Have you see your application folder in tomcat webapps or wtpwebapps directory?